# Регулярное выражение как разделитель для explode php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

можно ли использовать каким то образом регулярное выражение как разделитель в explode() ?

например когда есть строка

```
$str = 'word1[and]word2[or]word3';

$arr = explode('[*/+]',$str);
```

что бы получить все элементы в массив? или тут только через регулярное выражение и preg_match?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Для этого есть `preg_split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью explode – нет, нельзя, но можно использовать preg_split. Это как explode, только для регулярных выражений.
Как использовать: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php